# Linear Algebra quick Question over inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

In an inner product space, not necessarily $\mathbb R^n$, there are vectors $a$ and $b$ such 
that $||a||\cdot ||b|| < |\langle a,b\rangle|
$

Is this never true?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: Never true, this would contradict the Cauchy Schwarz inequality : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Comment: Oh right! thanks I knew this was familiar just couldn't remember the name of what it was